# How to do policy routing with systemd?

Tags: systemd, iproute2, coreos

I need to do policy routing on my CoreOS instances which use systemd.
But I haven't found any documentation or examples on how to do it with systemd-network.

How do I do that?

So far I have only managed to create another routing table by adding an entry to a new file `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables` and it is being recognised by the command line tools.

Ultimately, the I have two separate routers on the same subnet.  I want to ensure that traffic coming from one router destined for my host, is returned by the same router.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`systemd` adds policy routing support in version [235](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/NEWS). You can use `[RoutingPolicyRule]` sections to set policy routing if your `systemd` version is 235 or higher.

Supported [options](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.network.html#%5BRoutingPolicyRule%5D%20Section%20Options) are:

- `TypeOfService=` Specifies the type of service to match a number between 0 to 255.
- `From=` Specifies the source address prefix to match. Possibly followed by a slash and the prefix length.
- `To=` Specifies the destination address prefix to match. Possibly followed by a slash and the prefix length.
- `FirewallMark=` Specifies the iptables firewall mark value to match (a number between 1 and 4294967295).
- `Table=` Specifies the routing table identifier to lookup if the rule selector matches. The table identifier for a route (a number between 1 and 4294967295).
- `Priority=` Specifies the priority of this rule. Priority= is an unsigned integer. Higher number means lower priority, and rules get processed in order of increasing number.

Answer (score 1):

Support for multiple route tables isn't available in networkd today. It is something that could certainly be added though; perhaps you could share your rt_tables setup and explain your use case on [systemd-devel](http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel)?

Comment: I went crazy with CoreOS and was using it in an HA router config.  Firewall rules applied by running firewall script in a docker image.